# Lost rep but no record in the reputation log?

Tags: support, reputation

I seem to have lost 20 rep with no record as to why in the reputation log?

Some days ago I was on 917 rep. The following screenshot showing 912 rep is from Google Cache dated 22 Dec 2013. Since this date I received +5 (on 22 Jan) for an upvoted question. I also rec'd +2 today for accepting an answer (so total should have been **919**).

[image: Screenshot from Google Cache dated 22 Dec 2013 showing 912 rep]

However, according to the reputation log the only down-rep reported is a -5 on 8 Dec 2013 (*before* the above screenshot) when a "user was removed".

[image: Reputation changes]

So where has this 20 (919 - 899) rep gone?

I thought that maybe a question was migrated, but shouldn't this be reported in the rep log? And I don't see any change in my rep on the other sites in respect to this.

Comment: Well, your observation is correct. Your reputation was recalculated by the system and you "lost" 20 rep. *Why* that is, I don't know. But the current value is probably the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You has an answer on https://superuser.com/questions/446845/ worth 2 upvotes which was deleted, ergo the loss.

[image]

If you have selected "Show deleted posts" checkbox at the end of the page, that should show the deletion record

Comment: Ha, yes! I didn't know there was a "show removed posts" option - I hadn't scrolled that far down the page!